# Is it possible to remove focus from ZK combobox after list appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, zk

IE 10 has a bug
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/841043/blinking-text-cursor-overlapping-with-div

But I need somehow remove blinking cursor in ZKoss `Combobox`. The primary idea is to remove focus from input and try to get it to popup list. I think that if focus will be removed, blinking curcor doesn't appears behind popup list.

How can I remove focus from combobox's input after the popup list appears? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I solve it!

The point is to override method open of ZKoss's `Combobox`.

```
var _Cwgt = {};
zk.override(zul.inp.Combobox.prototype, _Cwgt, {
  open: function (silent) {
    var id = '#' + this.uuid + '-pp'; // get id of popup
    _Cwgt.open.apply(this, arguments); // call original
    jq(id).focus(); // give focus to the popup
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My hint is to set the combobox readonly.

If it is not possible, you can try to highlight the value of combobox.

I use this to get the trick, in .zul:

```
<combobox onFocus="@command('setFocusOnRow', evt=event)" />
```

and this in viewmodal:

```
@Command
public void setFocusOnRow(@BindingParam("evt") Event event) {
    Combobox c = (Combobox) event.getTarget();
    // select: highlight the value
    c.select();
}
```

However, the last time I used this it didn't work using Chrome.

Comment: Seems like I solved the problem via JavaScript. I have overrided `open` method of `Combobox` and get focus to popup `div` there.